# Estimate $\frac 1 {a+b} + \frac 1 {(a+b)(a+2b)} + \cdots + \frac 1 {(a+b)\cdots(a+kb)} + \cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose $a>1,b>0$ are real numbers. Consider the summation of the infinite series:
$$S=\frac 1 {a+b} + \frac 1 {(a+b)(a+2b)} + \cdots + \frac 1 {(a+b)\cdots(a+kb)} + \cdots$$
How can I give a tight estimation on the summation?
Apparently, one can get the upper bound:
$$S\le \sum_{k=1} ^\infty \frac 1 {(a+b)^k}=\frac 1 {a+b-1}$$
But it is not tight enough.
For example, fix $a\rightarrow 1$, and $b=0.001$, then $S=38.969939$, it seems that $S=O(\sqrt{1/b})$.
Another example: $a=1$, and $b=0.00001$,$S=395.039235$.

Comment: This is not a question at the research level. Ask it at  https://math.stackexchange.com .

Comment: How about (1/(a+b))(a+2b)/(a+2b-1)? Gerhard "That Gets It Even Closer" Paseman, 2019.03.14.

Comment: I have added an example. This is still not tight because it is linear in $b$.

Comment: An obvious simple upper bound is given by setting $a=0$, that is $e^{1/b}-1$.

Comment: If $b$ is small compared to $a$, you can write $(a+b)(a+2b)\cdots(a+kb)$ as $\exp(-\sum\log(a+ib))$, and use $\log(1+x)<x-\frac{x^2}{2}$. This yields $\mathcal{O}(b^{-1/2})$, but getting the right constants will be a bit of work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maple produces a closed-form expression for the sum under consideration by

```
sum(1/product(b*j+a, j = 1 .. k), k = 0 .. infinity))/(a+b)  assuming a>1,b>0;
```

$${\frac {a{{\rm e}^{{b}^{-1}}}}{a+b}{b}^{{\frac {a-b}{b}}} \left( -
\Gamma \left( {\frac {a}{b}},{b}^{-1} \right) +\Gamma \left( {\frac {a
}{b}} \right)  \right) }
 $$

Addition. So does Mathematica through

```
Sum[1/Product[b*j + a, {j, 1, k}],{k, 0, Infinity},Assumptions -> b > 0 && a > 1]/(a + b)
```

Comment: Asymptotically, as $a/b \to \infty$, this is bounded by $(a/e)^{a/b}$.

Comment: Mathematica 11.3 confirms $ S=O(\sqrt{1/b}).$

Comment: @user64494: You have recently tried to have a minor edit validated, but it got rejected. Immediately after, you submitted the same edit attempt once more. Please don't do this! It is not polite, it feels aggressive and it leaves the impression that you are desperately begging for those +2 reputation points that you get for each approved edit.